# Solving a programming puzzle

Tags: image-recognition

I have been solving a programming competition and one of the questions led me to this image of a man that I cannot recognize, any ideas?
[image]

Comment: That is Dennis Ritchie.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Comment: Thanks, @George, that is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dennis Ritchie, creator of the C language